# How to style little x in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

Is there a way to style little x that serve to remove selected items?
I getting it with vanilla js and jquery and with `:before` pseudo selector, and from all of them only pseudo selector(partialy) works. Can't style pseudo selector.

I want to have, instead that `x`, to have anything else. I tried targeting it, as i said before, but even if i use

```
document.querySelectorAll("#forma1 > span > span > span > ul")[0].childNodes[0]
```

which should target span that contains little `x`, it targets next `li` element. I also tried targeting it indirectly, by saying "target first li's previousSibling", but to no avail. It can not be targeted what ever i try.

My question is: Is there any way of changing text inside this span, instead of that little `x`?

Mucho kudos in advance.

**Edit1:**

Little `x`:

[image: little_x]

Comment: you should provide more details. we don't know your project, so what is this x? where is it placed? what are those "selected items" and where are they? please show your code so far, or at least post a picture of it

Comment: @NPcompete A x where you cancel selection. See edit.

Comment: ok, so your question is "how to put this little x into my list?", more than how to style it, am i right? well first of all, i think you have a bigger problem with your html structure, as it is bad practise to put multiple inline containers (span) into inline containers, and it is even worse to put block containers (ul) in inline containers. but despite of that, you could just wrap your X within a inline container and give it a class. then you can use your querySelectorAll("#forma1 .my-class-for-the-little-x")

Comment: @NPcompete x and spans is automatically created by select2 library and as i said before, traditional ways of targeting it are failed. So, i can't wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you still didn't show your code, so I just tried it out on the demo page of select2.org

you can do something like this (i'm using querySelector, but you can do it with querySelectorAll if you have multiple items):

```
let x = document.querySelector(".select2-selection");
let y = document.createElement("span");
let z = document.createTextNode("x");
y.classList.add("my-styled-little-x");
y.append(z);
x.append(y);
```

And now use CSS to style your class "my-styled-little-x".

E. g. something like this:

```
.my-styled-little-x {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.select2-selection__clear:before {
    content: "yourPlaceholderText";
    position: absolute;
    left: 11px;
    top: 45%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-weight: 400;
    color: black;
}
```

This is stuff what i looked for. It mimics placeholder text, but actually it serves same purpose as that small `x`.